# Where do Israeli nationalist Orthodox movements derive their Halacha?

Tags: halacha, rabbis, politics-government, communities, israel

**This isn't a question regarding Israeli politics or issues like that. This question is purely about where these groups *(Groups which followed Meir Kahane or similar voices*) developed or derived their Halacha and how their systems are structured.**

European Orthodoxy, for example, tends to follow a more understood structure ***(or at least more understood to me)***. You can see the community lines and Rabbinical dynasties and the various shifts from region to region and so on. You can find out quite easily where their traditions come from and who the current leaders and voices within these communities are today.

These Israel nationalist Orthodoxies seem to have kind of popped up randomly out of history. I can't pinpoint whether it all came from one specific movement or individual or if it's a bridging of various movements and individuals. Visually, they seem like an amalgam of various Jewish identities and community traditions which all *seem* affiliated yet all kind of stand individually on their own.

- You have Jews with natural beards and Peyos which look Breslov in style.
- You have Jews with none at all which look closer to M.O.
- You have Jews which wear obvious tzitzit out and about and others who don't.
- You have some who were white or seem to dress in relation to Breslov traditions. You have others who will wear jeans and button down striped shirts or sweaters.
- You have some who wear jeans or military style kakis with boots.
- I've even seem a few from such groups which wear aspects of more Orthodox Jewish dress (black suit jackets or black dress pants) with aspects of the above listed.

It's like a little bit of everything but they all sort of mix and match depending on the individual.

I never have gotten a straight answer about where these groups derive their Halacha or how their leadership authorities are structured around their Halacha.

**Do they have an equivalent to Chaim Kanievsky or similar** or someone who is extremely influential in their Halacha and religious issues? Is there really no organization at all?

I'm just curious as to where these movements derive their Halacha from.

Comment: From my understanding, Rabbi Kanievsky also isn't the centralized leader of the Charedim in Israel. In other words, Charedim also don't have one leader but many. As to the poskim of the Dati Leumi, we also have many. Rabbi Aviner, Rabbi Ariel, Rabbi Eliyahu, Rabbi Drukman, Rabbi Rimon, just to name a few.

Comment: @Harel13 there are indeed numerous gedolei yisroel in the chareidi 'camp' however most people of that hashkofo view him as the 'Sar shel Torah'

Comment: [R' Goren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Goren#Religious-Zionist_activism) was also an influential figure in this group.

Comment: @Harel13 If we're discussing contemporary poskei halacha in the Dati Leumi world, I would argue that R E Melamed is probably the most influential, owing to the popularity of his Peninei Halacha

Comment: @JoelK Likely any name that people will write here, I'll be nodding and saying: Him too. :D. B"H there are many names, many talmidei chachamim.

Comment: @Harel13 I wasn't attempting to say he represents all streams of Charedim opinion. I was simply using him as an example of an influential leader within a movement as a contrast. Does a similar figure exist in Israeli Nationalist Orthodoxy?

Comment: Well, many see the father of Dati Leumi to be Rabbi A. I. Kook and by extension his son, Rabbi T. Y. Kook, whose students are now leaders throughout the movement. Nowadays there are many influential leaders. I listed a few of them. Rabbi Melamed mentioned by @JoelK is another good example.

Comment: @Harel13 I thank you for the information. I was more just trying to get a general idea of how the movement formed and the various voices within it. I appreciate some of the names.

Answer (score -7):

> בַּיָּמִ֣ים הָהֵ֔ם אֵ֥ין מֶ֖לֶךְ בְּיִשְׂרָאֵ֑ל אִ֛ישׁ הַיָּשָׁ֥ר בְּעֵינָ֖יו יַעֲשֶֽׂה׃
> In those days there was no king in Israel; **every man did as he pleased**. [Judges.17.6?](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.17.6?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)

DISCLAIMER: my answer refers to the Israeli Zionist religious movements only.

1. IMHO (I was very close to those groups in my youth and I voted for them some 30 years ago), all Zionist religious groups are based on Jewish apocalyptic views, similar to those in the times of [the Great revolt](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-great-revolt-66-70-ce), where Rabbinic authorities submit to charismatic political leaders (saviors), similar to how R' Kivah submitted himself to Bar Kuzivah (Bar Kochbah).
2. Similar views were presented in the beginning of the 20th century by [R' Abraham Isaac Kook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Isaac_Kook) toward notable secular Zionist leaders, who were seen as sort of "God-nominated" Machichim. In this transition to the Messianic age, Halacha plays very little role, because the tradition holds that [most of] the Mitzvos will become obsolete.
3. It should be noted, that traditionally, all Zionist religious movements were closer to **secular Zionists' "national self-realization"** views than to Orthodox exilistic views, and the orthodox rabbis were never seen or accepted as authorities in the Zionist religious circles.
4. On the other hand, their approach to "Torah veAvodah" which initially meant a constant combination of the two became "one-after-the-other", i.e after the boys finish high Yeshivos where they are taught ways of Halachic discourse, they engage in Avodah (as divine will of course), but are on their own Halachicly, and don't require a constant and close Rabbinic guidance, unlike their Orthodox friends. (*Many of them do continue to study Torah in their shuls, but it is definitely secondary to their working for the living)*.

To wit, while you can see Orthodox Rabbis demanding voting for the UO parties as a religious commandment, Zionist religious Rabbis never stress that point.

4. The major Halachic problem for this movement was its ethnic diversity, it allowed boys and girls of all ethnic backgrounds to study in one place (unlike the Orthodox), and posed a serious Halachic problem. Despite various propositions to develop a unified approach (so-called "Nosach Achid"), this problem wasn't properly solved and most kids were advised to continue their family traditions. I remember myself in the Israeli army on Jewish High Holidays having three shuls - one overcrowded for Sefardim, one Minyan for Ashkenazim, and an empty one for Nosach Achid.

From all of the above follows, that one should not expect strong Halachic reasoning from religious nationalistic groups for anything related to their *political* views. While many of them are very pious and observant Jews, they are more orthopraxial than orthodox, i.e. keeping the practical Halacha while deviating from contemporary Orthodox views.

Comment: I take strong exception to your classification of the Dati Leumi world as non-Orthodox

Comment: @JoelK That's why I called it orthopraxial - keeping [fully for some] the Jewish practices but not the spirit of the contemporary orthodox movement. FOr example, they will tell - "Rabbis will not tell me where to live or whom to vote for".

Comment: I would be very, very wary of accusing entire communities of יראים ושלמים, מקפידים על קלה כחמורה, of non-orthodoxy, just because they subscribe to a somewhat more minimalist interpretation of the very modern notion of "דעת תורה" that has recently become popular in Israeli Chareidi societies. וד"ל ואכמ"ל

Comment: @JoelK I think you didn’t understand what I wrote at all. Orthopraxy means keeping all the practices and laws which they mostly do (to a different level). But they don't align with the orthodox rabbinic views on full submission to Rabbis and the centrality of Torah study in their lives. You will not see many (if any) Zionist religious men that make their living from studying Torah in Kollels, unlike about 50% of Orthodox.

Comment: You keep using that word “Orthodox”. I do not think it means what you think it means. (Hint: it is not a synonym for contemporary Israeli Chareidi society.)

Comment: "because the tradition holds that [most of] the Mitzvos will become obsolete." citation needed, as it seems to undermine the 13 principles of faith.

Comment: @robev please do your homework before critiquing: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%90

Comment: It's not my job to research your answer. Your answer should provide justification for its seemingly heretical statements.

Comment: You seem to have it backwards. Orthodox Jews have jobs and learn Torah too and don't ask their rabbis for economic policy advice. Orthoprax Jews are the ones who have "full submission" to rabbis and stay in kollel. They are certainly doing lots of religious actions, but that's not the traditional way to practice and believe in Judaism. It's something made up in the last century by "charedi" reactionaries.

Comment: Also I think it's ludicrous to suggest that since there's a statement in Chazal that Mitzvos will become בטל לעתיד לבוא, which is a vague statement with many interpretations, that any group would therefore stop following halacha **today**. This would equate religious zionists to sabbateans

Comment: Wow, so R' Akiva, who spent 24 years away from his family studying full-time, was only "Orthoprax" according to @DoubleAA. So were the 2200 full-time students (אוכלי שולחנו, as Rashi puts it) of Elisha, the 1200 of Rav, etc. (Kesubos 106a).

Comment: @Meir and according to the OP, R Yochanan HaSandlar was Orthoprax. Wow. That's why youre dumb if you take any of these generalizations too seriously. (And why this answer isn't very good.)

Comment: @DoubleAA "Lashon Hara," you bleat, but then are motzi shem ra on R' Yochanan Hasandlar, who's not mentioned anywhere in this answer, and on Al Berko, claiming that he said any such thing about him. שומו שמים!

Comment: @Meir I see no need to respond to that. Kol tuv.

Comment: @DoubleAA Because you have no response. Where is there the slightest evidence that R' Yochanan Hasandlar "submitted to charismatic political leaders"? Is your notion of "Torah" just making things up?

Comment: @meir I think you’re missing Double AA’s point, which is solely that R Yochanan Hasandlar did not ‘make his living from studying Torah’

Comment: @JoelK Neither I, nor the OP, nor anyone else has ever claimed that the _only_ valid way is to "make a living from studying Torah," so if that's what he meant, then he's arguing against a strawman. No, his claim is that those who study full-time are "Orthoprax," and that this is something invented only in recent times, which is easily disproved by the examples of R' Akiva et al.

Comment: @meir The OP wrote earlier in the comment thread that ‘they [Religious Zionists] don't align with the orthodox rabbinic views on full submission to Rabbis and the centrality of Torah study in their lives. You will not see many (if any) Zionist religious men that make their living from studying Torah in Kollels, unlike about 50% of Orthodox.’ It certainly sounds to me like RZs are being written out of the OP’s definition of orthodoxy for not enthusiastically supporting long-term learning for as many people as possible.

Comment: @JoelK There is, of course, a vast difference between saying that _few_ people should be learning Torah full-time and that _no one_ should. DoubleAA's position is the latter, that the whole concept is an invention of recent times, and that real "Orthodoxy" holds of no such thing. That is facially false.

Comment: Talk about strawmen...